# Is there an add on for the pysal library for generating a queen contiguity?

Tags: python, correlation, pysal

I am trying to perform a spatial autocorrelation function on a shapefile(shp). How do i generate a queen contiguity for this?

I read the pysal documentation and saw the 'queen_from_shapefile' but I get an error.

This is my code:

```py
shp= gpd.read_file(r'..\data\districts.shp')
Q_w = ps.queen_from_shapefile(shp)
```

The error i keep getting is

```
AttributeError: module 'pysal' has no attribute 'queen_from_shapefile'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate Queen contiguity from Geopandas GeoDataFrame using following script:

```
Q_w = ps.lib.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(shp)
```

`queen_from_shapefile` is not relevant since you are passing gdf anyway. I think it is no longer used, documentation might be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

could also use:

libpysal.weights.contiguity.Queen()